# How can i get all elements with a selector attribute with VanillaJS?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to get all elements with a specific `data-` attribute, but I need to manipulate they individually. Check my code:

**HTML**

```
<div data-something></div>
<div data-something></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-something]").onclick = function() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is how you can get all elements with a selector attribute and create an onclick listener for each element.

Run the snippet, and click the "click me -- A" or "click me -- B" links for a demo:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-something]');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function (element) {
    element.onclick = function () { 
        alert(element.innerHTML); 
    };
});
```

```html
<div data-something>click me -- A</div>
<div data-something>click me -- B</div>
```

You can also use `.addEventListener('click', someFunction)` instead of `.onclick = someFunction`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting all of them, but that means you're getting a [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), an array-like object containing all the elements that has to be iterated over

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-something]");

for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {

    elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    ...
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that performance-wide defining a function and reusing it is preferred.